# Scheduling while atomic when I mount USB memory second time

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

I'm working on our embedded system and when I mount the USB memory second time, I get this 'schedulling while atomic' error. After about 20 seconds, the mount succeeds with messages shown below.

I'm not that an expert and I don't know where to look in. Where should I look in? (linux3.3)

First mount works fine. and I used umount /usb to detach the memory stick.

```
# mount -t vfat /dev/sda0 /usb


BUG: scheduling while atomic: scsi_eh_0/328/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0384d9c : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02b0474 : command_abort+0x94/0xe0 ] [c0273a8c : scsi_error_handler+0x3e4/0x524 ] [c00462e8 : kt 
ckim: or mask
ckim: connected 
RESUME int
usb 1-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using aldebaran-hcd
ckim: or mask
ckim: connected 
RESUME int
BUG: scheduling while atomic: scsi_eh_0/328/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0384d9c : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02722a8 : scsi_send_eh_cmnd+0x64/0x280 ] [c0272574 : scsi_eh_tur+0x18/0x94 ] [c0272654 : scsi_e 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: scsi_eh_0/328/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c00462e8 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c0011540 : kernel_thread+0x34/0x50 ] [c0046530 : kthreadd+0xc8/0x148 ]
```

---

The problem was solved yesterday by fixing the interrupt service routine. The port status has not been properly reported as disconnected when I plugged the memory stick out. By fixing it, this problem disappeared. When I gave the mount command second time, the device was still recognized as connected when it is not there, and this caused a long no response situation I guess.

ADD :
After 4 months I though the problem was fixed, a few days ago, playing with the USB keyboard, I found the same problem appear when I disconnect the USB keyboard and re-connected it. The message is below just in case someone can give me a clue on what the problem is..

```
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000002
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fc2c : devtmpfs_delete_node+0xa0/0xc8 ] [c027920c : device_del+0x160/0x188 ] 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fc2c : devtmpfs_delete_node+0xa0/0xc8 ] [c027920c : device_del+0x160/0x188 ] 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fc2c : devtmpfs_delete_node+0xa0/0xc8 ] [c027920c : device_del+0x160/0x188 ] 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fc2c : devtmpfs_delete_node+0xa0/0xc8 ] [c027920c : device_del+0x160/0x188 ] 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_thread+0x34/0x50 ] [c0046dfc : kthreadd+0xc8/0x148 ] 
INSRMV int
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b7f0c : hub_thread+0xc94/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_th 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b4758 : hub_port_reset+0x134/0x458 ] [c02b5468 : hub_port_init+0x50/0x7a0 ] [c02b76f0 : 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b49c4 : hub_port_reset+0x3a0/0x458 ] [c02b5468 : hub_port_init+0x50/0x7a0 ] [c02b76f0 : 
usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using aldebaran-hcd
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b4758 : hub_port_reset+0x134/0x458 ] [c02b581c : hub_port_init+0x404/0x7a0 ] [c02b76f0  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b49c4 : hub_port_reset+0x3a0/0x458 ] [c02b581c : hub_port_init+0x404/0x7a0 ] [c02b76f0  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0037b78 : msleep+0x18/0x34 ] [c02b560c : hub_port_init+0x1f4/0x7a0 ] [c02b76f0 : hub_thread+0x478/0x11d8 ] [c0046bb4 : k 
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0780
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fb40 : devtmpfs_create_node+0xd0/0x11c ] [c0279998 : device_add+0x230/0x620  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
input: Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000 as /devices/platform/aldebaran-hcd/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input2
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fb40 : devtmpfs_create_node+0xd0/0x11c ] [c0279998 : device_add+0x230/0x620  
generic-usb 0003:045E:0780.0003: input: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000] on usb-aldebaran-hc0
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c02bcc78 : usb_start_wait_urb+0x98/0xcc ] [c02bceb4 : usb_control_msg+0xd8/0xfc  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c02fcf20 : usbhid_wait_io+0xa8/0x118 ] [c02fcff8 : usbhid_init_reports+0x68/0x110 ] [c02fd5c8 : usbhid_start+0x528/0x648  
input: Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000 as /devices/platform/aldebaran-hcd/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/input/input3
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fb40 : devtmpfs_create_node+0xd0/0x11c ] [c0279998 : device_add+0x230/0x620  
generic-usb 0003:045E:0780.0004: input: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 3000] on usb-aldebaran-hcd-1
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c03b5824 : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ] [c027fb40 : devtmpfs_create_node+0xd0/0x11c ] [c0279998 : device_add+0x230/0x620  
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000003
Modules linked in:
[c0046bb4 : kthread+0x78/0x8c ] [c00115b8 : kernel_thread+0x34/0x50 ] [c0046dfc : kthreadd+0xc8/0x148 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is problem in the kernel. It means that some part of kernel tried to do some non-atomic procedure while kernel was in atomic context. For example kernel tried to go to sleep.

Try to upgrade your kernel.

Comment: Oh, the problem was solved yesterday by fixing the interrupt service routine. The port status has not been properly reported as disconnected when I plugged the memory stick out. By fixing it, this problem disappeared. When I gave the mount command second time, the device was still recognized as connected when it is not there, and this caused a long no response situation I guess.

Comment: The same problem occurred again recently, this time it was an 'else' keyword preventing spin_unlock_irqrestore function from being called! So I removed the 'else' and it's ok now. Thanks!